# Adding newly-created object to Restangular collection

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I'm using Restangular with an AngularJS app and starting with a simple CRUD application.  The issue I am having is understanding how to add a new item to a pre-existing collection.

Within the controller the pre-existing collection is obtained in the service and made available on the scope:

```
$scope.data.items = Restangular.all('items');
```

A new item is created through a form and created on the server:

```
$scope.data.items.post(newitem);
```

I'd like to add this new item to the pre-existing collection but not sure how.  The [restangular sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6yDka?p=preview) just calls `Restangular.all('items')` again, which seems very wasteful given that all of the information is present.  Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
$scope.data.items.post(newitem).then(function(response) {
  $scope.data.items.push(newitem);
});
```

But this does not work.  How should I add to the collection rather than just refetch the entire collection each time I create a new item?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yeah @mgonto provided the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because what you're assigning to data.items is a promise.

If you change it to the following it should work:

```
Restangular.all('items').then(function(items) {
    $scope.data.items = items
});
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `$object` of your promise and return the newly added item in your POST response. Then you can splice the item into your Restangular collection. For example:

```
$scope.data.items = Restangular.all('items').getList().$object;

$scope.data.items.post(newitem).then(function (response) {
    $scope.data.items.splice($scope.data.items.length, 0, response);
});
```